# Can Flask's redirect be used without url_for?

Tags: python, flask

After following a tutorial, I have two views in my `auth` blueprint. I am confused over the different uses of `redirect`. The first view uses `redirect(url_for())` but the second omits `url_for`. Why is this? Is it not enough to use just `redirect('blueprint_name.route_name')`?

```
return redirect(url_for('auth.unconfirmed'))
```

```
return redirect('main.index')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one doesn't work as intended.

`redirect` takes a URL. `url_for` generates URLs. The second example redirects to the URL `main.index`, which doesn't exist. (And even if it did exist, it's unlikely that's what you wanted.)